# AngularDatatables: How to check all checkbox records in current page

Tags: jquery, angular, angular-datatables

AngularDatatables: How to check all checkbox records in current page and will Check only displayed page(first page) but unable to checked the table records...

I tried with below code,

Js:

```
     isChecked = false;
  checkuncheckall() {   
    if (this.isChecked == true) {
       $('.checkboxCls').prop('checked', false);
      this.isChecked = false;
    } else {
       $('.checkboxCls').prop('checked', true);
      this.isChecked = true;
    }
  }
```

HTML:

```
<th><input type="checkbox" name="id" (click) = "checkuncheckall()"></th>   

 <tr *ngFor="let person of persons">
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxCls" name="id" [checked]="isChecked" value="{{person.id}}"></td>
        <td>{{ person.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ person.firstName }}</td>
        <td>{{ person.lastName }}</td>
      </tr>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datatables-gitter-zdvjhv?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Your method checkuncheckall even not fired at all!

Comment: The function is triggered now,,,,but unable to check all records

Comment: Fixed the issue and updated the issue in the question..

Comment: // this.dtTrigger.next(); // You will found this line will force remove the checked/unchecked status see the forked demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datatables-gitter-tyhhb9?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: @Rajasekhar, you're using a very old version of Angular and a very, very old fashion data table (based in JQuery!!!) with a poor documentation.

Comment: Is this resolved now ?

Comment: Yes, its resolved and stackblitz have solution.